# Какая разница между двумя "text" в TextView?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В гугле не смог найти. Не понимаю разницы между двумя полями в Attributes. 
Это аттрибуты для простого Button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это довольно удобный параметр использует XML схему tools.

Делов в том что если вы напишите во второй строке или в XML примерно так:

```
text:text="Hello"
```

то у вас IDEA не будет ругаться, а в Preview вы увидите примерно такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но когда запустите приложение поле будет пустым, проще говоря, данное поле позволяет видеть как будет смотреться текст в Preview, но при старте приложения, View не будет прнимать данный параметр и будет пустым. Очень удобная фишка, при верстке по Мокам если они летят от дизайнера.

Аналог, что чаще всего иcпользуется это

```
tools:text="Hello"
```

Аналогичный prefix для XML tools

PS: возможно использовать с другими View

Comment: а что такое верстка по мокам ?:

Comment: @OlegKhegay данные фейковые

Comment: @elik да всё верно, это какие-то данные которые дизайнер подставляет, очень удобно потом смотреть, особенно если в дизайне что-то меняется, а это происходит всегда, а вы делаете 1 в 1 по его Mock-Up(готовому наброску). Вообщем это кучу проблем решает, для разработчик по Preview сразу можно понять, что за View открыта и где косяк, особенно если используете Constraint, точней BluePrint View, там все очень наглядно в итоге всё.

Answer (score 3):

Разница в том что один отображает данные и в превью и на девайсе, а второй только в превью (а на девайсе пустая строка)